# how to prevent recursion in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, recursion

I am creating a rollup summary on account's related contacts using flow in salesforce And currently getting issue with recursion in flow, I have created two flow for **creating and updating records** and **deleting records** and it will update the field in account object but whenever I delete the record it is triggering the **creating and updating records flow** as well, please need some guidance on this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You should consider using DLRS which solves all this without needing flow

Comment: It is much, much easier to do rollups using the free [DLRS tool](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) or the paid Rollup Helper app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either stablish some criteria about the data you're using as your record triggered flow, if you can identify some criteria under which you don't want to keep looping you can just avoid performing the Database operation and just finish the flow.

If you don't have it just create a new Boolean field , and update it accordingly on your flow when you don't want the other flows from firing and just do the process previously mentioned using that field as your criteria to finish the flow prematurely.